# How to return multiple string values from a method java

Tags: java, string, methods

I am unable to return both username and pass `String` values at the same time.

```java
    public static String executeLogin(String username, String pass) {
        int totalAttempts = 5;

        if (totalAttempts != 0) {
            if (username == "Javaprogram" && (pass == "Legend1@")) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect Login");
                totalAttempts--;
            }
            if (totalAttempts == 0) {
                System.out.println("Maximum number of attempts exceeded");  
            }

        }
        return "username,pass";                 
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, that's not how you [compare strings in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: You cannot return multiple values with a single method (unless the method is called multiple times).

Comment: That's not possible with java. Create an object instead (let's say `Credentials`) that holds both values and return an instance of said object.

Comment: Also I can't think of any logical reason you would want to return username and pass...you are passing them into the method... thus you already have them in the caller?

Comment: a subclass of Object or an array[]

Comment: Go the OOP route. Create a `Credentials` class which has a `String name;` and `String password` field. Add a constructor, some nice getters etc and then use this class instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: you should have your 'total attempts' variable outside the scope of the function!**

You can return a list of strings:

```
static int totalAttempts = 5;

public static String[] executeLogin(String username, String pass) {

    if (totalAttempts != 0) {
        if (username == "Javaprogram" && (pass == "Legend1@")) {
            System.out.println("Correct");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect Login");
            totalAttempts--;
        }
        if (totalAttempts == 0) {
            System.out.println("Maximum number of attempts exceeded");
        }

    }

    return new String[]{username, pass};
}
```

Comment: Why not just make a `Credentials` class and go the OOP way. Otherwise the user has to deal with how big the array actually is, maybe its empty or just one or three entries, who knows. It is just error prone.

Comment: i am trying to pass username and password from main method to the executelogin method.How to do that?